# Why can't Bernstein-Vazirani algorithm be classicaly computed in one try?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, bernstein-vazirani-algorithm

Instead of using n inputs (000...01, 000...10, ..., 100...00) and multiplying each one with the hidden number x, why can't we just try one input:  111...11 ?

I can't think of an example of a binary number x which we couldn't discover by multiplying it with only 111...11.
I assume I don't understand the problem correctly, but it is how I perceived it after watching Qiskit videos on Youtube.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you input $1111\ldots 1$ to the oracle for the Bernstein-Vazirani problem, you get a 1 bit output which just evaluates $111\ldots 1\cdot s$ (where you're trying to learn $s$). In other words, you only learn whether the number of 1s in $s$ is even or odd. That is nowhere near enough to reconstruct the whole of $s$.

Indeed, this is the start of the argument for the classical lower bound: to learn $s$ I need to find out $n$ bits of information. Each use of the oracle can give me at most 1 bit. Thus, I must use the oracle at least $n$ times.